# The same SQL query has a different performance and execution plan on two similar databases

Tags: database, postgresql, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

We have two PostgreSQL 11.16 databases, running on the same Linux distribution Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.9 (Maipo), but on a different host. The hosts are similar in sizing and the databases are similar in data. When we execute the following query on both databases it takes about 26 seconds on database A, and less than 1 second on database B.

```
select all pdb_personeelsdocument.r_object_id, pdb_personeelsdocument.r_object_type "r_object_type", 
pdb_personeelsdocument.i_vstamp, dm_repeating.r_aspect_name, pdb_personeelsdocument.i_is_replica, 
pdb_personeelsdocument.i_is_reference, pdb_personeelsdocument.acl_name 
from pdb_personeelsdocument_sp  pdb_personeelsdocument, pdb_personeelsdocument_rp dm_repeating 
where ( (pdb_personeelsdocument.r_object_id 
in (select r_object_id from dm_sysobject_r where i_folder_id= '123'))  
and  ((pdb_personeelsdocument.document_status= 'Goedgekeurd')) ) 
and (pdb_personeelsdocument.i_has_folder = 1 and pdb_personeelsdocument.i_is_deleted = 0) 
and dm_repeating.r_object_id=pdb_personeelsdocument.r_object_id order by 1
```

We looked at the query execution plan (by using explain (analyze)) in pgAdmin. On database A we see that the execution plan first tries to perform a nested loop (see attachment) and on database B it doesn't. Furthermore showing the execution plan graphically on database A doesn't work and gives an empty screen, on database B we get a nice graphical execution plan. Finally if we remove the 'order by 1' from the query it performs great on both databases.

Query Execution plans (text):

Database A | https://explain.depesz.com/s/4Wfu#html

Database B | https://explain.depesz.com/s/eRur#html

We tried to reindex all the indexes, and did an analyze for all the tables that were used in the execution plan. However, with no result. Does anyone know what more actions we could take?

Comment: Execution plans are better shared as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) or through https://explain.depesz.com/

Comment: Are the databases on the same machine, same OS? What is/are the OS? What are the machine(s) specifications?

Comment: In all cases the statistics are way off and that’s normally not a good thing. But non of my tools can analyze pictures to get the details from a query plan, please use plain text.

Comment: By the way I would rewrite the subquery as a join and the other join also as a proper join to make the query readable

Comment: Excuse my delayed reply, but thanks for the explain.depesz.com link @a_horse_with_no_name I added two explian.depesz.com links with both query execution plans. I hope this clarifies the problem a bit

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I added the OS name and version. The databases are not on the on the same machine, but they use the same OS.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I added the explain.depesz.com links. Hope this clarifies the problem

Comment: The slow query is also using [parallel query](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/parallel-query.html) so you might want to read through the information at the link to see if the databases are set up differently for that. Also from the explain.depesz.com Hint tab: "You have sort node (#6) that is using disk space to sort.This is because your work_mem setting is too low. Increasing it can make the sort run in memory, or, at least, use less of disk. Sort used 78080kB, so you would need to set your work_mem to at least that much to have a chance at sorting in memory only."